# How to reset the input value without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reset the input value after clicking post button without refreshing the page

The following code is in while loop

```html
<input class="comment" type="text" placeholder="Write comment"><button class="comment_post" onClick="reset()">Post</button>
```

I have used

```js
function reset(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('comment').value=null;
}
```

```html
<input class="comment" type="text" placeholder="Write comment"><button class="comment_post" onClick="reset()">Post</button>
```

please provide the code

Comment: just set the value to => `""` after clicking post

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list - array `type` hency why its not working

Comment: Try this => `document.querySelector('.comment').value = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function reset() {
    $(".comment").val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="comment" type="text" placeholder="Write comment">
<br><br>
<button class="comment_post" onClick="reset()">Post</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using jQuery file include, you can simply use the following function.

```js
function reset()
{
  document.getElementsByClassName('comment')[0].value='';
}
```

```html
<input class="comment" type="text" placeholder="Write comment">
<br><br>
<button class="comment_post" onClick="reset()">Post</button>
```

Comment: I was going to include the **JavaScript** solution as well, but with your answer that won't be necessary anymore. I answered with the **jQuery** version because I saw that the OP included the **jQuery tag**.